# What is the best practice around inheriting a custom fragment

Tags: android, inheritance, android-fragments

I'm making an Reddit app for my android exam and I have a question about inheritence.

I have a Fragment who has a RecyclerView. That recyclerview contains a list of redditposts. My app consists of multiple subreddits (funny, gaming, news, etc..). Every subreddit has his own Fragment. I have some methods that every Fragment has to have. (a showProgressBar, hideProgressBar, populateResult, etc...) I think it would be simple if i just make an Fragment class where all the subreddit Fragments can inheritance from. I could put all the methods in that fragment class because the methods are the same for every subreddit fragment. But my lecturer said that is a bad use of inheritance. So does anybody have a best practice around this problem?

This is the fragment i'm talking about:
package com.example.thomas.redditapp;

```
public class FunnyFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Bind(R.id.funny_recyclerview)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Bind(R.id.progressBarFetch)
    ProgressBar progress;

    private RedditHelper helper;

    private RedditPostRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

    List<RedditPost> redditPosts;

    public FunnyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helper = null;
        helper = new RedditHelper(SubRedditEnum.funny, this);
        redditPosts = new ArrayList<>();
        startLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_funny_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        showProgressBar();

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mAdapter = new RedditPostRecyclerViewAdapter(redditPosts, mListener, mRecyclerView);

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                redditPosts.add(null);
                helper.loadListFromUrl();
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        return view;
    }

    protected void startLoad() {
        if (helper != null) {
            helper.loadListFromDb();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isTaskRunning()) {
            showProgressBar();
        } else {
            hideProgressBar();
        }
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void hideProgressBar() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void showProgressBar() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void populateResult(List<RedditPost> result) {
        if(!redditPosts.isEmpty()){
            redditPosts.remove(redditPosts.size() - 1);
        }
        redditPosts.addAll(result);
        mAdapter.setLoaded();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected boolean isTaskRunning() {
        if (helper == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (helper.getStatus() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the hideProgressBar(), showProgressBar() and populateResult() in my helper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a long standing mantra in programming that states: "Favor composition over inheritance"

You can read about the details of this statement and a lot of discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from).

In this case, inheritance is unnecessary because you can simply build 1 Fragment and, on initialization pass it the subreddit, thus avoiding any constraining links between a super and subclass that may not even have any sort of polymorphic relationship.

Comment: I know that in my case I just could build 1 Fragment but I wanted an answer that I could use in the future for my next builds, and you provided me that, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Do you mind accepting my answer?